# How to send data to smartphone from ESP32 using BlueTooth (Lua NodeMCU)

Tags: lua, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, nodemcu

Right now I have managed to create a Bluetooth advertisement using the code below:

```
bthci.reset(function(err) print(err or "Ok!") end)
bthci.adv.setparams({type=bthci.adv.CONN_DIR_HI}, function(err) print(err or "Ok!") end)
bthci.adv.setdata(encoder.fromHex("0708486f6d65494f"), function(err) print(err or "Ok!") end)
bthci.adv.enable(1, function(err) print(err or "Ok!") end)
```

The ESP32 is recognised by the smartphone using a Bluetooth scanner app.
I also added this piece of code:

```
uart.setup(1, 921600, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 1)
-- error handler
uart.on(1, "error",
  function(data)
    print("error from uart:", data)
  end)
  
uart.start(1)
uart.write(1, "Hello, world\n")
```

To try to send something to the smartphone, but when I try to connect to the ESP32 I get 'Connection failed: gatt status 133'.

My BT configuration is like this:

```
CONFIG_BT_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_BTDM_CTRL_MODE_BLE_ONLY=n
CONFIG_BTDM_CTRL_MODE_BR_EDR_ONLY=n
CONFIG_BTDM_CTRL_MODE_BTDM=y
CONFIG_BTDM_CTRL_BLE_MAX_CONN=9
CONFIG_BTDM_CTRL_BR_EDR_MAX_ACL_CONN=7
CONFIG_BTDM_CTRL_BR_EDR_MAX_SYNC_CONN=3
CONFIG_BT_HCI_UART=y
CONFIG_BT_HCI_UART_NO_DEFAULT=1
CONFIG_BT_HCI_UART_BAUDRATE_DEFAULT=921600
```

The only examples I can find are about c with the Arduino IDE. Anyone implemented something similar in Lua so I can see an example?

Comment: Your advertisement seems to setting the type of advertisement broadcast and the Shortened Local Name to "HomeIO" to use in the advertisement. This is why the phone fails to connect because there is no GATT server setup for it to connect to. The uart section seems unrelated to Bluetooth. Have your reviewed the Host Controller Interface Functional Specification in the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification) as it looks like that library only supports setup with raw HCI commands.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have misunderstood some things. So do I need to add something to the advertisement? It seems that UUIDs are important but I am still trying to understand what they do. Is there any example of a simple use case you can show me?

Comment: There might be some useful information for you in this resource: https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/ The HCI commands are very low level and I can't help you much there.